# How to maintain aspect ratio on an Android Gallery

Tags: android, gallery, aspect-ratio

I have an Android Gallery setup on a layout with both the width and height set to Fill_Parent. This works great for smaller screens, but as the display size grows into the tablet sizes, the Gallery stretches to a layout that is taller than it is wide. At this point, there are no more side images on it - that is, just the main selected image is visible. I want to have at least a small amount of the side images visible so the user knows the view is scrollable.

Does anybody know how I can do this?

Is it possible to maintain an aspect ratio while still using fill_parent? Is it possible to set the Gallery view to show a certain amount of the side images? etc?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The Gallery class is pretty limited and personally I tend not to use it. Have you considered using a [ViewPager](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/08/horizontal-view-swiping-with-viewpager.html) instead?

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, If you are using

> android.widget.Gallery

then the implement a custom adapter to the view, and set a layout wrapped to each items inside the gallery view. If you still don't understand what I just said, I would try to generate some reference code.

Comment: This is what I am currently doing but I set the image size to the minimum of the parent (the Gallery) height/width so that the image scales to same of the Gallery on different screen sizes.

Comment: What I did find that works - though seems more like a hack? - is to set the image width and height to the following (in this case for a ratio of 4:5) - if the parent (gallery view) width*.8 < parent height, use parent width*.8 otherwise use the minimum of parent width/height. This seems to allow the Gallery and images to stretch as large as the fill_parent allows and maintains at least enough ratio between each image that a sliver of the previous and next images still show inside the Gallery.